# convert time string to date object javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, datetime, d3.js

I'm trying to plot D3 timeseries by referring :
http://mcaule.github.io/d3-timeseries/

which takes Date in this format : 'new Date('2013-01-01')

Now, I have following array:

```
            var data =[{
                "time": "2017-06-23T23:37:20-07:00",
                "value": 25.189767114257663
            },
            {
                "time": "2017-06-23T23:37:30-07:00",
                "value": 24.637318860009692
            },
            {
                "time": "2017-06-23T23:37:40-07:00",
                 "value": 24.896462306379043
            },
            {
                "time": "2017-06-23T23:37:50-07:00",
                "value": 24.348000192323468
            }]
```

I need to give this array as input to the d3 timeseries function. But I'm unable to plot anything as above time is not a Date object. How do I append or convert that time string to date object. Because I absolutely need to have that new Date thing otherwise that function is not at all executing.

I tried to convert time into date object using:

```
data.map(function(ele) {
ele.time = new Date(ele.time);
});
```

So, this thing appended Zone to all the times. When I tried to give this array as input to d3 function, it doesn't work.

Comment: you can preprocess `data`, convert all time string to date object, and use the result new data object as the input to d3.

Comment: no, you've converted it to a date **string** - `data.forEach(item => item.time = new Date(item.time))` will give you Date objects in the time property

Comment: I've tried doing some thing like above. Please check edit.

Comment: yeah ... map **returns** a new array, which you're ignoring ... so you may as well use `forEach` instead of `map` ...

Comment: `it doesn't work` is an often used phrase on stack overflow that is redundant (why else would you be asking a question) and meaningless by itself - do you get errors in the (developer tools) console? what do you observe? how does it differ from what you expect?

Comment: Yeah it gives a new array of this form {"time":"2017-06-24T06:37:20.000Z","value":25.189767114257663}{"time":"2017-06-24T06:37:30.000Z","value":24.637318860009692}{"time":"2017-06-24T06:37:40.000Z","value":24.896462306379043}{"time":"2017-06-24T06:37:50.000Z","value":24.348000192323468} . Why I will ignore this?

Answer (score 1):

You can map the timestamp to a date object by iterating over data and assigning a new field called date.

```
data.forEach(function(elem, index, arr) {
  arr[index]['date'] = new Date(
    arr[index]['timestamp'].split('T')[0]);
});
```

Pretty basic string splitting, and there are probably more elegant solutions, but here's a start.

Comment: can you tell me what is wrong with what I did, as I'm also converting it into a date object?

Comment: Would you mind sharing your code? I just edited my answer, so it might be more helpful now.

Comment: what you are doing will give same result as what I'm doing.As given in the link, I need something of this form: [{date:new Date('2013-01-01'),n:120,n3:124,ci_up:130,ci_down:118} ...]

Comment: its given in question